# url_for not using default_url_options[:host] value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I've got a view for an ActionMailer that includes a few different links. I'm running it on localhost:3000 right now, and so I've set that as such in a file called `setup_mail.rb` in app/initializers (as indicated [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3?view=asciicast)):

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
```

When I go to use `url_for` in the view, it doesn't seem to pull this value. If I then add `:host => "localhost:3000"` to each `url_for` tag, they work properly. But they don't work without that included.

I have another tag, `project_url`, which is as it appears: a link to a specified Project. This functions, including the host value, with just `project_url(@project)`. Why would one work but not the other?

From everything I've read, setting the `default_url_options[:host]` in an initializer should allow me to omit the `:host` value in the `url_for` tag. Obviously, it's not the worst thing in the world to just add that value, but it seems unnecessary and it means that when I eventually host the project somewhere I'll have to go through and change that value all over the place. But worse than that, it's something that I don't understand. I'm still learning as I go here and so I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#label-Generating+URLs) is pretty clear on this

> When you decide to set a default :host for your mailers, then you need to make sure to use the :only_path => false option when using url_for. Since the url_for view helper will generate relative URLs by default when a :host option isn’t explicitly provided, passing :only_path => false will ensure that absolute URLs are generated.

You could create your own helper to use instead of the `url_for` to force `:only_path` to be `false`

```
def your_url_for(options = {})
  options.reverse_merge! only_path: false
  url_for(options)
end
```

You could also monkey patch rails to force this as the default, but that's left up to you :)

This all would be in addition to adding

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "YOUR HOST" }
```

to `config/application.rb` or equivalent.

Comment: So what I'm gathering here is that I can't really avoid that extra parameter - I can just avoid having to duplicate the host that many times. But short of messing with the method, or creating a new one to use, I'm going to have to use either `:host` or `:only_path` in every `url_for` tag. Even though this doesn't hold true for things like `project_path`? That's kind of a bummer.

Comment: If you create a helper of your own like I described, or monkey patch `url_for` itself to overload the default `:only_path` option, and choose to use `url_for` directly, that appears to be correct. I rarely have a need for `url_for` in my applications, so it's never been a real concern for me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems `:only_path` option is false which is by default. so that is why you need to provide  `[:host]` either explicitly for every tag or set default options for `url_for` which would apply to all tags.  here is how to set default host:

put this code in your Application controller & it should work.

```
helper_method :url_for
def default_url_options(options)
  { host: 'localhost:3000' }
end
```

For more details check [set url_for defaults](http://lucastej.blogspot.in/2008/01/ruby-on-rails-how-to-set-urlfor.html)

Comment: This code looks antiquated. I'm in Rails 3.2. Looking at the comments, this is still valid, but is this still an ideal solution? You're saying I need to provide :host explicitly for every tag, but I don't. As I pointed out above, `project_url` is properly using the default host. And why are sites like railscasts suggesting the method I've used above instead of what you're suggesting?

Comment: You misunderstood. `ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]` should work & always has worked for me. However, in your case it doesn't. That's why I am suggesting to try and set it via `default_url_options` & see if it works. so try dropping the above code in your app controller

Comment: Alright fair enough, so you're suggesting this as a backup? I appreciate it. I'll keep it in mind. +1. But I'd like to figure out what's causing the problem in the first place.

Comment: To know the problem, code is needed. Try you can uploading a sample rails apps on github which reproduces the problem that you are describing here. Then someone might be able to help. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of tampering with the global default setting which imho shouldn't be changed after initialization you can simply define a method `default_url_options` in your mailer just like you can do it in a controller:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def default_url_options
    { host: Tenant.current(true).host }
  end

  def confirm(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: t(".subject_confirm"))
  end
end
```

Answer (score -3):

You're setting the default in ActionMailer::Base,  but appear to expect it to reset the default for ActionController::Base.

A <%= link_to %> inside your mailer view doesn't necessarily know anything about the fact that it's inside a mailer view.

Comment: I'm not using a `link_to`, I'm using `url_for`, which everywhere I've seen implies is what I should be using for ActionMailer. And I'm using it inside a view for an ActionMailer, not for a Controller (if I properly understand the distinction).